# What's the difference between Dart's analyzer and linter?

Tags: dart

You must have seen inside a `analysis_options.yaml`:

```
analyzer:
  exclude: [build]
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false

linter:
  rules:
    - camel_case_types
```

Are both used at compile time? What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer is that they have focus on different things.

The goal of the [analyzer](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer) is to check that your program is *valid*. It checks for syntax errors and type errors. Historically, in Dart 1, it was the only way to get type checking because compilers ignored types, but in Dart 2 that's no longer the case.

The analyzer ended up added more checking than what the language required. It can detect dead code or definitely wrong assignments, even when the language allows them, because it has a better static analysis than the language specification requires.
In general, the analyzer warns about *invalid* programs or likely *problems*.
Some warnings are enabled by default, and other you need to enable, because they could lead to false warnings. The gravity of each problem problem can be configured as error, warning, hint (or ignore). Being invalid Dart is always an error.

The [linter](https://pub.dev/packages/linter) is developed as a separate project. It only works on valid Dart programs, and it is intended to enforce a coding *style*. The language doesn't care whether your classes are `Capitalized` and your variables are `lowerCase`, but the style guide says they should be, and the linter can enforce that style by reporting a lint error if it's not satisfied.
That's what the linter does: It reports style violations. Since style is subjective, all lints need to be enabled, there are no lints enabled by default.

The lints can also be very specific. There are lints which only apply to code using specific libraries, in order to enforce a specific style for that code.
A project like Flutter might enable some lints by default in packages that it creates.

The analyzer existed before the linter, and some warnings added to the analyzer would perhaps have been made lints if they were added today.
Both depends on annotations in [`package:meta`](https://pub.dev/packages/meta) for adding metadata to drive warnings/lints.
The analyzer now *includes* the linter and provides errors/warnings/hints/lints from both, so a programmer will rarely need to make a distinction. The main difference is that lints are documented in the [linter repository](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/) and discussions about new lints happens there, independently of changes in the analyzer.

The Dart package [`pedantic`](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic) defines [a set of lints](https://github.com/dart-lang/pedantic/blob/master/lib/analysis_options.1.9.0.yaml) which are used for all internal Google code. It's very strict and opinionated, with the goal of preventing both potentially dangerous code and any unnecessary style discussion. [Other packages](https://pub.dev/packages/effective_dart) provide [other sets of lints](https://github.com/tenhobi/effective_dart/blob/master/lib/analysis_options.1.2.0.yaml).
There is no official set of lints recommended by the Dart team (yet), as long as you follow the [style guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart).

Edit: There now are official lints recommended by the Dart team: [`package:lints`](https://pub.dev/packages/lints).

Comment: While this rings true somehow, the linter and the analyser have exactly the same set of rules. So, the above still doesn't really explain the situation.

Comment: As stated, the analyzer includes the linter and all its lint rules. It also has more. There is no stand-alone linter program, so the linter can't have the same set of rules as the analyzer. (It's just not always easy to tell which is which.)